# Getting a "You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input'" error in tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I'm attempting to build a neural network with a weighted loss function in tensorflow using `tf.contrib.learn.estimator`. I consistently get the same error when running the code.
Here's the modelfn for the estimator:

```
    def model_fn(features, targets, mode, params):

  """Model function for Estimator."""

  # Connect the first hidden layer to input layer
  # (features) with relu activation
  first_hidden_layer = tf.contrib.layers.relu(features, 20)


  # Connect the second hidden layer to first hidden layer with relu
  second_hidden_layer = tf.contrib.layers.relu(first_hidden_layer, 20)

  third_hidden_layer = tf.contrib.layers.relu(second_hidden_layer, 20)

  # Connect the output layer to second hidden layer (no activation fn)
  output_layer = tf.contrib.layers.linear(second_hidden_layer, 1)

  # Reshape output layer to 1-dim Tensor to return predictions
  predictions = tf.reshape(output_layer, [-1])

  # Calculate loss weighting false negatives up
  sess=tf.InteractiveSession()
  t=tf.constant(0)
  def weightedloss(prediction=[], target=[]):
      losssum = 0.0
      for x in range(len(prediction)):
          if prediction[x] == 1 & target[x] == 0:
              losssum += 1.0
          elif prediction[x] == 0 & target[x] == 1:
              losssum += 9.0
          else:
              losssum += 0.0
      return tf.constant(losssum)
  print(list(predictions.eval(session=sess)))

  loss = weightedloss(list(predictions.eval(session=sess)), list(targets.eval(session=sess)))

  # Calculate root mean squared error as additional eval metric
  eval_metric_ops = {
      "rmse":
          tf.metrics.root_mean_squared_error(
              tf.cast(targets, tf.float64), predictions)
  }

  train_op = tf.contrib.layers.optimize_loss(
      loss=loss,
      global_step=tf.contrib.framework.get_global_step(),
      learning_rate=params["learning_rate"],
      optimizer="SGD")

  return model_fn.ModelFnOps(
      mode=mode,
      predictions=predictions_dict,
      loss=loss,
      train_op=train_op,
      eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)
```

Here's how I'm using that model fn in my code:

```
nn = tf.contrib.learn.Estimator(model_fn=model_fn, params=.003)
print("reachedfit")
# Fit model.
#classifier.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train, steps=1000)
nn.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train, steps=1000)
print("reachedpredict")
y = list(nn.predict(x_test))
```

And, lastly, here's the error I'm getting:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input' with dtype double
         [[Node: input = Placeholder[dtype=DT_DOUBLE, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Neither reachedfit nor reacherpredict is being printed.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from

```
 print(list(predictions.eval(session=sess)))

 loss = weightedloss(list(predictions.eval(session=sess)), list(targets.eval(session=sess)))
```

where you try to eval the `predictions` and `targets` tensors without feeding the session with inputs.

Also `model_fn.ModelFnOps` expects a `loss` tensor, so you shouldn't define your loss as you did, but instead you should define loss using only tensor operations. Have a look to the **Defining loss for the model** section in this [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/estimators) (highlighting is mine):

> The ModelFnOps returned by the model_fn must contain loss: a **Tensor** representing the loss value, which quantifies how well the model's predictions reflect the target values during training and evaluation runs. The **tf.losses** module provides convenience functions for calculating loss using a variety of metrics.

You'll feed your estimator with `data`and `target` when running the `nn.fit`and `nn.evaluate` methods as described in the same document:

> Running the [...] Model
>
> You've instantiated an Estimator [...] and defined its behavior in **model_fn**; all that's left to do is train, evaluate, and make predictions.
>
> Add the following code to the end of main() to fit the neural network to the training data and evaluate accuracy:
>   Fit
>   `nn.fit(x=training_set.data, y=training_set.target, steps=5000)`
>
> Score accuracy
>   `ev = nn.evaluate(x=test_set.data, y=test_set.target, steps=1)`

Comment: Does turning loss back into a tf.constant fix the latter problem?  Also, what inputs should I feed the session--i.e. how are placeholders formatted, and do my placeholders have to match the dimensionality of the feature tensors?

Comment: is my nn.fit line above inaccurate(x_train is the training set data, y_train is the training set target)?

Comment: It should be fine then.